# Android ListView transcriptMode="normal" smooth animate when items are added

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm trying to use a ListView in an Android messaging/chat application and I want to animate smoothly when items are added (but only if the user is viewing the latest message, if they're viewing previous messages I don't need to animate).

I'm using stackFromBottom="true" and transcriptMode="normal" which gets me close to the behavior in terms of scrolling to the newest messages if the user is looking at the latest message, and not doing it if they've scrolled to previous messages. It seems like the behavior of transcriptMode="normal" or "alwaysScroll" does the scrolling to the new message very quickly. I want there to be some way to animate that scrolling over the course of 1 second.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

set

`android:transcriptMode = "disabled"`

and instead use

```
int lastIndex = listView.getChildCout() - 1;
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastIndex);
```

everytime you add a new item.

Comment: Typo: `getChildCout()` should be `getChildCount()`